# Is there a way to split piping in R to two output functions?

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr

I need to save latex and word versions of summary tables. Is there a pipe operator that can split the input into two outputs? Ideally I'd like something that will take `species_tab` and save into latex and word at the same time.

```
library(datasets)
library(flextable)
library(gt)

species_tab <- iris %>% 
  tabyl(Species)

species_tab %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  gtsave(filename = "species.tex")

species_tab %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  save_as_docx(path = "species.docx")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `%T>%` operator from `magrittr` that is used when you want to return the `lhs` of the operator rather than the output of the `rhs`. However, it's messy and not really the use case for the operator, so would go with @akrun's solution. But there are cases where you don't have to use `{ }` and the tee operator is preferable to the normal pipe.

```r
library(magrittr)

species_tab %T>% 
  { gtsave(data = gt(.), filename = "species.tex")} %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  save_as_docx(path = "species.docx")
```

Comment: This one worked for me, but only once I removed `flextable()%>%`. I can't seem to edit (Suggested edit queue is full), can you? I'll mark as correct anyway since this comment will be posted

Answer (score 4):

One option is to wrap with `{}`

```
library(datasets)
library(flextable)
library(gt)
iris %>% 
   tabyl(Species) %>% 
   {. %>%
    gt() %>% 
     gtsave(filename = "species.tex")
    . %>%
     flextable() %>%
     save_as_docx(path = "species.docx")
}
```

Comment: Can you later add how the {} and dots work?

Comment: @ibm The documentation for `help("%>%")` says `...  The reason for this is that in most use-cases this produces the most readable code. For example, iris %>% subset(1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0) is equivalent to iris %>% subset(., 1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0) but slightly more compact. It is possible to overrule this behavior by enclosing the rhs in braces. For example, 1:10 %>% {c(min(.), max(.))} is equivalent to c(min(1:10), max(1:10))`